# Incomplete/Corrupted downloaded files

Tags: c#, .net, download, httpwebrequest

I have made this little tool wich goes through a list of image links and download them to the hard drive, however, some of the pictures are incomplete ([Check this picture](http://i.imgur.com/1CYSDFi.jpg)) and they don't even raise an exception. The code below shows the download method I'm using in my tool.

```
private void Download(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        Request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        Request.Timeout = 60 * 1000;
        FileInfo ImageFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, Path.GetFileName(url)));
        if (!ImageFile.Exists)
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (Response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
                {
                    using (FileStream FStream = new FileStream(ImageFile.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096))
                        Response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(FStream, 4096);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Downloading: {0}\r\nMessage: {1}", url, e.Message);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out whether the problem is on the server side or there is something wrong with my code, so what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling `Flush()` after you've read the data? It looks like the last part of the stream isn't being written out.

Comment: Isn't the using statement supposed to do that for me or does it just close the FileStream? Also, it only happens sometimes, the other times there is no problem with any of the downloaded pictures and that's what got me confused!

Comment: The using just calls Dispose(), which neatly destroys the object. There's no guarantee that the stream will be flushed before it is destroyed. The times when it did work are probably due to the stream being flushed by some other factor. Try calling Flush() and see how you get on

Comment: Ok. I'll give it a try and report back later.

Comment: It seems that was the problem all along. Thanks a lot, you really saved me there.